# $r^2 R_{rr}+rR_r+(r^2 \lambda - s^2) R = 0$ - Bessel's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Let the equation $r^2 R_{rr}+rR_r+(r^2 \lambda - s^2) R = 0$, where $R=R(r)$. Is anyone could explain to me how convert this D.E into Bessel's equation?

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda=0$, there is no hope (but it can be easily proven that $R(r)=A\,r^{+s}+B\,r^{-s}$ for some $A,B$ if $s\neq 0$, and $R(r)=A+B\ln(r)$ for some $A,B$ if $s=0$).  If $\lambda\neq 0$, let $\lambda=\nu^2$.  Define $\rho:=\nu\,r$.  Show that $R(r)=u(\nu\,r)$ where $u$ is a solution to the Bessel equation of order $s$.

Comment: This is exactly why what there is in the solution sheet. How do you decide to define $\lambda=\nu^2$? Could you quote me a reference if any?

Comment: Search for "eigenvalue problem" together with "Bessel equation."

Comment: I have not seen website that explicitly discussing the subject. Would you be able to tell me more?

Comment: What about Page 25 of http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253/Lecture3.pdf?  Or http://www2.fiu.edu/~meziani/NOTE12.pdf.  In fact, what more do you need from this substitution $\lambda=\nu^2$?

Comment: @george :  $r\frac{d}{dr} f(ar) = ar f'(ar) = r\frac{d}{dr}f(r)|_{r-> ar}$. The presence of $r$ above and $dr$ below leaves the term scale invariant in $r$. The same is true of $r^2 \frac{d^2}{dr^2}$. So, when you scale in the argument, the only term affected is the $r^2f(r)$ term, and that's how you get rid of the scale factor $\lambda$.